# django datetimefield filter not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-forms, django-views

I m trying to filter the date from the mysql table. if i dont put the date filter in ...my search form works fine...when i put that date filter it basically fails the form.is_valid() statement.
It works fine without the filter **created_at**
I have tried all the filter type for the **created_at**
some of them gives this error the other doesnt give no error but, the none of the search filter give any results...

this is the error that i get:

```
ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value
```

forms.py

```
class AllTablesForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=250, required=False,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Title'}))
    url = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=250, required=False,
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Url'}))
    description = forms.CharField(label='', required=False,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Description'}))
    created_at = forms.DateTimeField(label='', required=False,
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Created At'}))
```

where i do my search forms *views.py*

```
def search_form_table(request, pk):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=pk)
    t = create_model(table_name.name)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AllTablesForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            title = cd['title']
            url = cd['url']
            description = cd['description']
            created_at = cd['created_at']
            # print created_at
            query = t.objects.filter(title__icontains=title,
                                     url__icontains=url,
                                     description__icontains=description,
                                     created_at__gte=created_at)
            return render(request, 'search/search_table.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                                'form': form,
                                                                'details': query})

        else:
            form = AllTablesForm()
        return render(request, 'search/search_table.html', {'form': form})
```

right now i have **created_at__gte** and i get that error. it basically says that my **form.is_valid()** is not valid.

for example: if i put **created_at__exact** i don't get no error...but my search doesn't work... i don't see no results...and none of my other filters work.

If i take the **created_at** out of the filter ...the search filter works and it gives me results.

Please help me. Thank you

***ADDED***

Oh almost forgot. The date format that it shows when i list the field is:
***Sept. 19, 2017, 11:12 a.m.***

And the format in the mysql created_at column is:
***2017-09-08 12:16:38***

I do want to created that filter something like the phpmyadmin filter.
Where a window pops and show you the calendar to select the date and the time frames.

Comment: what it does t = create_model(table_name.name)  ?

Comment: you can't do filter by 'created_at' when the value is None. If if value exists, then filter.

Comment: t = create_model() is part of my models...it gives the name to the db_table in  AllTables model

Comment: the value it exists...it does show me the values of that column created_at when i dont put the filter for it

Comment: can you paste the get url with query parameters when you get the created_at value ?

Comment: with the created_at filter or without?

Comment: with created_at__exact filter it gives me a 404 because the form doesn't pass form.is_valid

Comment: you should use in built javascript calender in template and use strftime and strptime in python to change the format of time according to your requirement

Comment: you mean place input_format in the form for DateTimeField?

Comment: django will convert the string to datetime object within form itself when you call is_valid(). No need for strptime etc. But from the template, you have to pass a format in which django can encode it to a datetime object.

Comment: Oh k I think I get it now...I'm going to try that

Comment: But which filter should I use for created at...__exact,__range etc?